# How to convert implicitly to Unit?

Tags: scala

Is it possible to execute an implicit **custom** conversion to `Unit` for a given object ?

What I mean is defining a conversion like:

```
implicit def toUnit(m: MyClass): Unit = println("Hello")
```

And using it as follows:

```
val x: MyClass = new MyClass() // no conversions
val y: Unit = new MyClass() // 1
new MyClass() // 2
```

I have defined some conversions to other objects as above: `Unit` is the only class that is not working.

I think it should work, at least in case *1*, but I can't see `Hello` printed on the console. Why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work because `Unit` is handled specially by the compiler. You're able to assign `MyClass` to `Unit` because of value discarding. There are no implicits involved.

From the [scala spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions):

> If e has some value type and the expected type is Unit, e is converted to the expected type by embedding it in the term { e; () }.

So what happens here is that `new MyClass()` is changed by the compiler to

```
{ new MyClass(); () }
```

Comment: So, there is no way to override the default behavior ?